# How can I make height-matched absolute value symbols without including packages?

Tags: math-mode, mathjax

I want to use the following formula:

[image: Formula from physics.SE]

or, in markup:

```
$$| \sum_i \vec{v}_i \Delta t_i  |$$
```

I want to make nice height-matched absolute value delimiters, but I can't use any packages (I'm using MathJax). Is there a way to do this in pure math mode?

Comment: MathJax questions are in almost all cases off-topic here, and your question for me belongs to them. You could ask instead in the [MathJaX Help Forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users).

Comment: [This](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-do-we-feel-about-mathjax-jsmath-other-spin-offs) meta post says they're a borderline case, but still allowable. I'll rephrase the question to make it less MathJax-specific.

Comment: Do `\big|`/`\Big|`/`\bigg|`/`\Bigg|` work?

Comment: BTW on [so] it should not be off-topic. There is also a tag, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax.

Comment: @Speravir: Yes, but I was hoping for something more automatic, where I don't have to manually pick the size of the delimiters.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `\left|....\right|` for automatic sizing, or as Spervir comments: choose the size explicitly as (for example) `\bigl|....\bigr|`